# Google oauth 2.0 subdomains. fail google login using my subdomain

Tags: oauth, subdomain

I have used google OAuth 2.0 but google login is not success. I have update below information's for google auth
[image]

I try to put subdomain in to Authorized domain field I'm getting below validation errors.
[image]

after try to sign in using Gmail getting below issues.
[image]

Please help me to fixed this issues

I need to sign in/sign up using google auth